# Bootstrap dropdown button won't open any links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just can't figure out why my dropdown button is not working. I can't see any errors in the console, I have tried with calling css files in the head element and at the end of the body, that hasn't changed anything. This is my navigation menu with a dropdown button in it:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">SLEEKER</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Theme option content -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li><a ng-click="changeTheme(1)">Flatly</a></li>
                            <li><a ng-click="changeTheme(2)">United</a></li>
                            <li><a ng-click="changeTheme(3)">Cerulean</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Theme option content -->
    </div>
    <!-- Container -->
</nav>
```

And I have included all the files needed at the bottom:

```
 <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.{{theme}}.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/spinner.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- load angular libraries -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- APP scripts -->
<script src="app/hotels/hotels.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems you are using Angular Bootstrap.js relies on jQuery and it is recommended not to use jQuery in Angular projects as it conflicts with how angular manipulates the views. You won't be able to bind variables to components (like buttons) without using small hacks. UI Bootstrap is the solution to use in Angular projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are missing the `bootstrap.js`

take a look with your `nav`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">SLEEKER</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Theme option content -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li><a ng-click="changeTheme(1)">Flatly</a>
              </li>
              <li><a ng-click="changeTheme(2)">United</a>
              </li>
              <li><a ng-click="changeTheme(3)">Cerulean</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Theme option content -->
  </div>
  <!-- Container -->
</nav>
```